# How do I get results from my work queue task?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8

I've implemented a simply work queue that receives tasks from a number of different threads. I want these tasks to return a value to their source thread, but can't figure out how to do that.
I've considered using a future, but there's no way to explicitly set the future's value. I could use a property, but I don't believe those are thread safe.

Every task is an implementation of DBRequest. The actual content varies, but the result of all activities is a string.
An asynchronous thread creates a DBRequest and submits it to the queue. The queue runs the task, which produces a string. How do I get that string back to the thread that created the DBRequest, and how can I cause my creator thread to wait for the result?

```
public interface DBRequest {
    String execute(VdtsSysDB vdtsSysDB, BoardLoad currentLoad);
}

public class DBQueue implements Runnable {
    private static DBQueue dbQueue;
    private LinkedBlockingQueue<DBRequest> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
    private VdtsSysDB vdtsSysDB = new VdtsSysDB();
    private ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DBQueue.class);
    private boolean kill = false;

    private BoardLoad currentLoad;
    private ProgressController progressController;

    public static DBQueue getInstance() {
        if (dbQueue == null) synchronized (DBQueue.class) {
            if (dbQueue == null)
                dbQueue = new DBQueue();
        }
        return dbQueue;
    }

    private DBQueue() {
    }

    public ReentrantLock getLock() {
        return lock;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        LOG.info("Starting DBQueue loop. Kill {}.", kill);
        while (!kill) {
            DBRequest dbRequest = removeRequest();
            if (dbRequest != null) {
                lock.lock();
                String result = dbRequest.execute(vdtsSysDB, currentLoad);
                lock.unlock();
                if (progressController != null) Platform.runLater(() ->
                        progressController.updateDisplay(currentLoad));
            }
        }
        vdtsSysDB.getEntityManager().close();
    }


    public void addRequest(DBRequest dbRequest) {
        try {
            queue.add(dbRequest);
            LOG.info("Added request.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Can't add element.", e);
        }
    }

    private DBRequest removeRequest() {
        DBRequest result = null;
        try {
            //result = queue.poll(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            result = queue.take();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Exception.", e);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public void killDBQueue() {
        kill = true;
        LOG.info("Shutting down DBQueue.");
    }

    public static void start() {
        Thread thread = new Thread(DBQueue.getInstance(), "DBQueue Thread");
        thread.start();
        LOG.info("Starting DBQueue.");
    }

    public BoardLoad getCurrentLoad() {
        if (currentLoad == null)
            currentLoad = BoardLoad.getLastOpenLoad(vdtsSysDB);
        return currentLoad;
    }

    public void setCurrentLoad(BoardLoad proposedLoad) {
        // We can only have one open load, and by definition, the current load is open. So close it.
        if (this.currentLoad != null && !this.currentLoad.equals(proposedLoad)) {
            currentLoad.close(vdtsSysDB);
            if (proposedLoad != null) {
                this.currentLoad = vdtsSysDB.getEntityManager().find(BoardLoad.class, proposedLoad.getId());
            } else this.currentLoad = null;
        }
    }

    public ProgressController getProgressController() {
        return progressController;
    }

    public void setProgressController(ProgressController progressController) {
        this.progressController = progressController;
    }
}
```

EDIT: I'm using this queue to synchronize database access, reducing the need for locks and ensuring that requests are completed sequentially. I don't believe there is any other way to achieve this sort of asynchronous request -> synchronous request change.
But I'd love to have that belief changed.

Comment: `CompletableFuture` provides a way to set a future's value.

Comment: You might want to run this by [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com). There are quite a few synchronisation problems in your code.

Comment: Your queue sounds like `ExecutorService` not a queue. You can submit tasks to `ExecutorService` which returns `Future` back. So thread that submits task to execute can call `Future.get()` to wait for result.

Comment: @teppic [Please do not refer questions with broken code to Code Review.](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5777) The [cross-post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/207594) is likely to be closed as off-topic.

Comment: @200_success. Ah. My apologies. I was unaware of the protocol.

Answer (score 1):

You should add a reference to the submitting thread in your `DBRequest` interface and implement a `setResult(String result)` (or similar) method to receive the result.
You can implement a `CountDownLatch` waiting  (or similar) on your submitting thread `run()` method to wait setting latch up when sending request to queue and down in `setResult` method.
If I'm not clear just let me know and I'll elaborate.

Comment: @MyStackRunnethOver thanks for fixing code parts. Still learning SO.